# Is https a pre-requisites for csrf token approach to prevent csrf attacks?

Tags: security, csrf, websecurity

With the csrf token approach, when server sends form to the client, it also sends a csrf token. And when the client fills the form and posts it to the server, the server validates whether the token is same as what it had sent along with the form. This method prevents csrf attack because hacker cant guess the csrf token value when trying to generate a form post request.

Am I right to say that https is a pre-requisites for csrf token approach to prevent csrf attacks? Otherwise if it were a http request, the hacker can intercept the form, token and make changes and submit the form again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no -as concept- , as one could say that a csrf attack would be possible over an https connection using an outdated TLS protocol for example, so ¿Would be TLS v1.3 required to prevent csrf attacks? Of course https will add another layer of protection over the connection but at a conceptual level I'd say that https is not 'required' for the CSRF token to work, but it's in a practical one.

[OWASP itself says](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf)

"HTTPS by itself does nothing to defend against CSRF.
However, HTTPS should be considered a prerequisite for ANY preventative measures to be TRUSTWORTHY."